# How to create Auto columns on the basis of their names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hope your doing well!

I'm trying to find out how to create columns on the basis of their names, if anyone has done this before, could you please guide me.

## sample data-(text file)

```
 SlNo
   1
   2
   3
   4
 Name
   A
   B
   C
   D
 Group
  ABC
  DEF
  XYZ
  LMN
 Grade
   A+
   A
   B
   C
 Percentage
    10%
     20%
     30%
     40%
```

Like 6columns data has been combined into a single column,I want to split all the data on the basis of the their names and create a dataframe.

Is there any way to auto create them, for example:- once SlNo completed and detect text "Name" it should create new column till it ends and detect next column name.

My code does on manual way

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def X(filename, vals_per_col):
  With open('Sample.txt','r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
  return{lines[i]:lines[i+1 : i+36] for i in 
    range(0,Len(lines),val_per_col+1)}
 df=pd.DataFrame(X('Sample.txt',35))
```

Thank you all for overwhelming response but my question, without manual intervention, is there anyway to create column heading and their respective data below on framework.

## Example:-

First I'll create column SlNo...and will read till 1,2,3, 4/5 or 100 next when it see next column header "NAME" it should automatically create a new column and iterate till it end...and so on keep looping

Comment: Is there something that seperates the end of line prior to a new "name" from the end of line prior to another data-point? Maybe a different seperator?

Comment: Thanks for quick response,.. No nothing! Everything is one below another and it's a text file. On above program I've to specify the number (for example I+36) to get data but I don't want do that way...

Comment: How did you end up in this situation? Also, your code needs some refactoring.

Comment: Well... I extracted text from image file and now I'm converting that one to CSV...  When text got extracted all the columns created below one another, then I've to divided them on the basis of row number but sometimes it get messy  so I want to automate bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try out the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def X(filename):

with open('Sample.txt','r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
    columns=[]
    data=[]
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        if(i%5==0):
            columns.append(lines[i])
        else:
            data.append(lines[i])
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(data,(5,4)).T,columns=columns)
    return df

df=X('Sample.txt')
```

[image]

Please try out this snippet of code.Here we are calculating the count of number of rows and creating dataframe acording to that number:

```
import pandas as pd
def divide_chunks(lines,count):
    for i in range(0, len(lines), count):  
        yield lines[i:i + count] 

def X(filename):

    with open('Sample.txt','r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
    columns=[]
    data=[]
    count =0
    low = lines.index('Name')
    high =lines.index('Group')
    count= high-low
    rows = list(divide_chunks(lines,count))

    df=pd.DataFrame(rows).T
    df.columns=df.iloc[0]
    df=df.drop([0],axis=0)
    return df
df=X('Sample.txt')
```

Comment: If I've more rows, SlNo 1 to 100then

Comment: In if loop replace 5 with 101 as if(i%101==0) and  replace the line df=pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(data,(5,4)).T,columns=columns) with df=pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(data,(5,100)).T,columns=columns)

Comment: Thanks for code but there is again manual intervention, my code do the same thing my point of view is like define column names iterate till column name match.. if match create other column or else keep looping till you get

Comment: These column names are fixed?

Comment: Nope... It's keep changing... But once we've format we can change the column name

Comment: Hey... thanks for code... Second program is working but need last help if(lines[i]=='Name'):
            break
        else:
            count = count+1.... If I want to give multiple column name will it work.. like if(lines[i]==('Name','Group','Grade'):
            break
        else:
            count = count+1

Comment: Hi..It will work.We are taking the count the number of entries in the dataframe.In if loop you have to give the 2nd column's name always(In this case it is 'Name').Thanks.

Comment: I got it but when I remove all the data from column SlNo and give second column heading on program, I'm getting lots of columns...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203086/discussion-between-lakshmi-intel-and-beginner).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
a=df[0].str.contains('[a-z]', regex=True).cumsum()
grps=df.groupby(a)
dfn=pd.concat([y.reset_index(drop=True) for _ , y in df[0].groupby(a)],axis=1, keys=range(0,len(grps)))
dfn.columns = dfn.iloc[0]
dfn = dfn.reindex(dfn.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
dfn.columns.name = None
print(dfn)
```

**output**

```
SlNo    Name    Group   Grade   Percentage
0   1   A   ABC     A+  10%
1   2   B   DEF     A   20%
2   3   C   XYZ     B   30%
3   4   D   LMN     C   40%
```

Comment: Where to place your code? After df=pd.Dataframe?? Or how

Comment: I have updated the code all the way from reading the `txt` file to the expected output. This is the c\whole code for your usage. The file name `data.txt` is the name of the file in which the data is present. If you have the data in a different file, use that name.

Comment: The assumptions here is that ONLY the column header has lowercase alphabets since there is no other distinguishable feature of the header . If that is not the case, then you will get a different output.

Comment: Thank you but it's not working...I'm getting pandas.errors.parserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2

Comment: can you change the first line to `df=pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None)` and try once?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this approach. It's quite intuitive, as is based in slicing the data from value 'X' to value 'Y'.

```
#read and load file in pandas
data = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', header=None)

toDict = {}

#getting column and rows
for i in range(len(data)):

    c = i*5         #column formula
    s = (i*5+1)     #records formula

    if c<len(data) and s<len(data): 
        col = data.iloc[c].to_list()
        rows = data.iloc[s:s+4].values.tolist()
        row = [val for sublist in rows for val in sublist] #flatten the list
        toDict[col[0]] = row
    else:
        break


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(toDict)


print(df)
    SlNo  Name  Group  Grade Percentage
0     1     A    ABC     A+        10%
1     2     B    DEF      A        20%
2     3     C    XYZ      B        30%
3     4     D    LMN      C        40%
```